# How to import googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer to my android studio

Tags: android, github, import

I'm a newer in Android and i wish to import [this project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) to my android studio.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this full](http://maxrohde.com/2014/08/18/import-github-project-to-android-studio/) document. It will explain in details step by step whats need to be done.

#### Step 1: Install git for Windows

It can be downloaded for free from git-scm.com.

Most settings available during the installation process should be compatible with Android studio. Just choose the settings you deem the most appropriate.

#### Step 2: Link git executable to Android Studio

Open Android Studio and got to Settings. In the Setting dialog open the page Version Control / Git. Here define the path to the git executable you have just installed.

#### Step 3: Get the Path to your Repository from Github

Go to the GitHub page and get the HTTPs path to your repository.
For instance:  https://github.com/mxro/WallOfTheWiseAndroid.git

#### Step 4: Import the Git project to Android Studio

Go to Android Studio and go to Menu / VCS / Checkout from Version Control / Git
[image]

Fill in the required information: username, password, url etc

Now the project should be imported to Android Studio and you should be able to commit and push future changes back to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of android studio (The 1.3 beta) you can go to File -> import Sample

Then you can select the project you wanted. It's under the getting started heading.